# Store cardholder data in PayPal or other service provider?

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, credit-card, recurring-billing, pci-dss

I'm working on a e-commerce website with PayPal direct payment. Our customers are supposed to enter their credit card information in the page that hosted by PayPal, so that our server will NEVER touch the cardholder data.

Our problem is that we want to provide the convenience so that the returning customer don't have to enter credit card information every time, and we don't want to store or even touch the cardholder data.

Instead, we want to store this sensitive data in PayPal so that next time we can just provide something like a CustomerID to ask PayPal access the credit card information to complete the purchase.

Is that possible to do with PayPal or other service provider?

PS. We also tried Intuit Payment Wallet. It can store the cardholder data but it need us to transmit these data to their server to create a "wallet".

Answer (score 0):

If it's PayPal you can do it either through Reference Transaction, or Recurring Billing.  You also have PayPal's Adaptive Payments pre-approvals, although these require that the buyer have a paypal account.

For true credit card storage, where you only keep a token, you have to use a service like these guys:
https://www.braintreepayments.com/